# Trying to convert SQL Server to MySql for class

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, syntax

I am trying to convert code given by teacher that is in SQL Server to MySQL. It ultimately should allow me to input information to the table that was made. This is a for a guest book assignment. Unfortunately I cannot find the correct syntax as I have never worked with SQL programming in general before.

I have tried using brackets,semi colons and commas for the information as well as adding a delimeter which eliminated the "Unrecognized statement type (near PROCEDURE)" error messages that had initially been in the programming as well.

Teachers code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spInsertGuestbookEntry
 @GuestBookName varchar(200),
 @GuestBookEntry ntext,
 @GuestbookEmail varchar(200),
 @GuestBookIP varchar(20)

AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

INSERT INTO Guestbook 
 (GuestbookName, GuestBookEntry, GuestbookEmail, GuestBookIP, GuestBookDate)
VALUES
 (@GuestbookName, @GuestBookEntry, @GuestbookEmail, @GuestBookIP, GetDate())
END
GO
```

My modifications:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE spInsertGuestbookEntry
 @GuestBookName varchar(200)
 @GuestBookEntry text
 @GuestbookEmail varchar(200)
 @GuestBookIP varchar(20)
 @GuestBookDate date

AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

INSERT INTO Guestbook 
 (GuestbookName, GuestBookEntry, GuestbookEmail, GuestBookIP, GuestBookDate)
VALUES
 (@GuestbookName, @GuestBookEntry, @GuestbookEmail, @GuestBookIP, @GuestBookDate)
END 
GO
```

The error messages that I got was "Unrecognized data type. (near))" That error message is by the @GuestBookName varchar(200)

Comment: The parameters to the `PROCEDURE` must be separated by commas (apart from the last parameter) just as the teacher's code.

Comment: Please review this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html fix your code based on the examples there and google mysql set nocount. AND there is no GO in mysql. also read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-objects.html to understand why you have to set delimiters,

Comment: The only change you really need to make is change `GetDate()` to `CURDATE()`

Comment: SQL is the language, which is implemented in MySQL as well. You mean Microsoft SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `spInsertGuestbookEntry`(
    IN `str_GuestBookName` VARCHAR(200),
    IN `str_GuestBookEntry` TEXT,
    IN `str_GuestbookEmail` VARCHAR(200),
    IN `str_GuestBookIP` VARCHAR(20)
)
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
CONTAINS SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT ''
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Guestbook 
    (GuestbookName, GuestBookEntry, GuestbookEmail, GuestBookIP, GuestBookDate)
    VALUES
    (str_GuestBookName, str_GuestBookEntry, str_GuestbookEmail, str_GuestBookIP, CURRENT_DATE());
END

$$
```

Key points to consider:

- Distinguish between `table column_name` and `procedure input parameter`.
- `@` is used to create user-defined variables in MySQL and you should be using this if your parameter is of type `OUT/INOUT` while calling procedure.
- In procedure/function creation, simple variable names are used, not with `@` symbol otherwise while using these parameters, MySQL will look for some variable with this name, not the input parameter.

Comment: I think you just did ops assignment.